# wordpress.com vs local install

Tags: documentation

Are the differences documented somewhere between the software wordpress.com uses and the wordpress you use to install locally ? I'm running into subtle differences that cause bugs when I develop locally then deploy to wordpress.com.

One difference is the local instal editor being encapsulated in an iframe whereas wordpress.com uses a class to try and isolate styles to the editor. Both my remote site and local install are using wordpress 6.4.3 - but based off the different behavior it feels like wordpress.com has customizations on top of version 6.4.3

Comment: The iframe in the editor is unrelated to .com vs '.org'. It's based on whether you're using classic meta boxes or blocks built with an older API version: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/07/18/miscellaneous-editor-changes-in-wordpress-6-3/#post-editor-iframed

Comment: thanks for that link - I'll dig in, however I'm using my own theme with my own blocks along with those builtin to 6.4.3.  All my blocks are version 3 - so not sure how that could apply.  The only thing I can imagine is if any wordpress.com plugins which can't be removed are causing this behavior - which imo would indicate a difference between wordpress.com vs local install

Comment: WordPress.com provides its own blocks, they might not all be v3.

Comment: Thanks so much @JacobPeattie - if you want to post an answer I will give you credit instead of myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically regarding the iframe discrepancy - Jacob Peattie was right in the comments.  This was caused by jetpack's builtin blocks not being registered with version 3.  Once I disabled them via Jetpack -> Settings -> Writing -> Composing and unchecking "Jetpack blocks give you the power...", the iframe appeared as expected.

[Here's the link](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/07/18/miscellaneous-editor-changes-in-wordpress-6-3/#post-editor-iframed) explaining the iframe behavior correlated with the block api version 3

My question was more broad than this specific issue, however there are probably many small incompatibilities such as this which will not all be documented in one spot.  If I run into more I will post additional questions.